# Machine Learning algorithm for XML file generation

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, machine-learning

I have a game application with characters that have to cross mazes. The game can generate thousands of different mazes and the characters can move according to users choice and cross the maze manually. We needed to add the possibility to show a correct way out of each maze. Therefore we added the possiblity to move the characters according to an xml file.

This XML file is very complex, usually around thirty-fifty thousands of rows. lets say its in the following structure (but much more complex):

```
  <maze-solution>
  <part id="1">
  <sector number="1">
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>1250></start-position>
            <angle>23.43</angle>
            <duration>0.44</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>run</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>light</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>4223></start-position>
            <angle>233.43</angle>
            <duration>0.32</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>walk</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>1231></start-position>
            <angle>84.134</angle>
            <duration>0.454</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>run</action-type>
        <character>2</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>932></start-position>
            <angle>34.43</angle>
            <duration>0.50</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>duck</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>   
  </sector>
  <sector number="2">
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>1250></start-position>
            <angle>23.43</angle>
            <duration>0.44</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>run</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>light</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>4223></start-position>
            <angle>233.43</angle>
            <duration>0.44</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>walk</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>1231></start-position>
            <angle>84.134</angle>
            <duration>0.454</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>run</action-type>
        <character>2</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>
    <action>
        <equipment>heavy</equipemnt>
        <movement>
            <start-position>932></start-position>
            <angle>23.43</angle>
            <duration>0.44</duration>
        </movement>
        <action-type>duck</action-type>
        <character>1</character>
        <protection>none</protection>       
    </action>   
  </sector>
  <sector number="3">   
  </maze-solution>
```

At the moment, we have the ability to analayze each maze using a CNN algorithm for image classification and generate an xml that represents a way out of the maze - meaning that if the characters will be moved according to that file, they will cross the maze. That algorithm has been tested and can not be changed by any means.

> The problem is that most of the times the generated file is not the
>   best one possible (and quite often it is very noticeable). There are
>   different, faster, better ways to cross the maze.

We also have thousands (and we can get as many as needed) files that were created manually for saved mazes and therefore they are representing an elegant and a fast way out of the maze.  The ideal goal is that someday, our program will learn how to generate such a file without people creating them manually.

To conclude, we have plenty of XML files generated by a program compared to the hard-coded XML files. There are thousands of pairs - The file the program generated, and the "ideal" file version that a person created. (and we can get infinite number of such pairs)
Is there a way, using those thousands of pairs, to make a second step algorithm that will "learn" what adjustments should be made in the generated XML files to make them more like the hard-coded ones?

I'm not looking for a specific solution here but for a general idea that will get me going. I hope i made myself clear but if I missed some info let me know and I will add it.

Comment: "algorithm has been tested and can not be changed by any means" and "most of the times the generated file is not the best one possible" - very poor tests, I would say.

Comment: Yes, the requirements are different than they were before. And now it can not be changed. Is there some sort of method or a general approach to deal with such a case?

Comment: The best solution would be the one(s) with the shortest total "duration".  So with xml you can easily sun the duration times.  Then for comparison you can group by the Sector Number and Start position between ideal results and actual results.

Comment: @jdweng The shortest duration solution isn't always the best, there are many different factors, amount of life lost during the way, energy wasted (an in-game life and energy of course), and difficulty etc etc. The hand-written solution is sometimes longer in terms of duration but has less risks and less resources used and wasted, so the comparing is not that easy. Also, the full XML complexity is not provided here. I want a suggestion in terms of generic approach/algorithm to adjusting XML files and machine learning from what I have rather than suggestions about this specific xml structure

Answer (score 7):

I think you're barking up the wrong tree. A machine learning algorithm to convert the output from you "immutable" algorithm to better solutions based on user-provided solutions seems like a lot more trouble than it's worth.

To me, this sounds like an application of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), since you're trying to find the shortest path in a maze, and *that's literally what this algorithm is designed for*. Of course, any shortest-path algorithm your heart desires would also suffice, but Dijkstra's is one of the more common approaches. Based on this comment you provided on your post:

> The shortest duration solution isn't always the best, there are many different factors, amount of life lost during the way, energy wasted (an in-game life and energy of course), and difficulty etc etc. The hand-written solution is sometimes longer in terms of duration but has less risks and less resources used and wasted

the edge weights on your graph are not just distance, but should factor in all of these costs associated with navigating the maze. Since this is very complex, it might also be useful or interesting to provide multiple "best" solutions using different calculations of edge weight which minimize the use of each the resources individually (time, life, energy, ...) as well as one or more that minimizes some combined score.

One other thing: if this is true:

> the comparing is not that easy

how are you determining that user solutions are better?

Lastly, you said the following in your original post (emphasis mine):

> At the moment, we have the ability to analayze each maze using a CNN algorithm for image classification and generate an xml that represents a way out of the maze - meaning that if the characters will be moved according to that file, they will cross the maze. **That algorithm has been tested and can not be changed by any means.**

But *why?* The way this is phrased makes it sound like you wrote the algorithm, so why can't it be changed?

Comment: Maybe I messed up with how I phrased but the algorithm was not written by me and can not be changed (we don't even have it's code). Regarding your other idea, maybe Dijkstra could work, but the thing is that we have thousands of solutions written manually by the *developers*, and not users solution as you mentioned. A huge amount of time was invested into those solutions and each of them is treated as the best. Because we have so many of those good solutions, an algorithm that would make use of them is what we want - A machine learning algorithm. The question is which kind

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your question and comments, you don't want change algorithm for finding the best path and only, you are look for finding the best solution from generated solutions.

> You should notice that machine learning approaches are designed for
>   optimizing some solutions by changing some factors like changing paths
>   according weights in your issue to find best solution or close to
>   best. But your issue is another story because you just need to a
>   algorithm for checking XML files and finding the best without any
>   changing in solutions.

To sum up, you need to a some testing approaches that it's very hard for each person that find one of them without knowing your scope of programs exactly.

Comment: I have one generated solution and one best solution for thousands of mazes. Basically I'm asking if I can do machine learning here to get best solutions of new mazes

Comment: @S.Peter is it correct for new mazes, at first, you create solutions?

Comment: The cnn algorithm I have generates me a valid solution. I want to optimize it with another step algorithm

Comment: @S.Peter Could you change solutions for generating new solutions?

Comment: No I can generate only one solution for each maze.

Comment: @S.Peter If you can change solutions for finding the better solutions,  some optimization approaches like *Ant Colony Optimization* https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234065233_Shortest_Path_Problem_Solving_Based_on_Ant_Colony_Optimization_Metaheuristic or *Genetic algorithm* http://www.ent.mrt.ac.lk/iml/ICIA2005/Papers/SL008CRC.pdf can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with wlyles answer. Here are my thoughts:

There is an important question: How did you developers decide which was the best way? Do you know the exact weights of importance for the relevant measuring key data.
For example total durations importance could be 0.2; live lost = 0.2; special items = 0.1; extra lives gained = 0.4;
If you know this, you can easily compare a lot of different solutions to find your best one. But with your optimal solutions you should be able to generate such metrics or train a CNN with differnt solutions and their quality (0-1).

You do need different solutions of the maze to compare them though!
If you dont have those solutions, you have to create them. It is not possible to fix your xml easily. Maybe there are parts of the xml that you can keep, but you need to write something to create new movement solution(s). Either by writing an algorithm which takes uses your weights to create the best solution or by creating a lot of different solutions and then comparing them to find your best one.

Maybe I got you wrong, but I dont think little adjustments in the xml file help, you need bigger changes in the xml (to the relevant parts at least).

This might be obviously, but you dont really want to use the xml directly, but a parsed version of it. Otherwise you wont get any usable solution.

Comment: By the fact that we know the weights as you mentioned, we can create a scoring method for each maze and measure it's "distance" from the optimal solution. We do need big adjustments in the file. Why do I need different solutions of the maze?

Comment: I am assuming that it is difficult to write an algorithm that creates a perfect solution when using the weights. I assume that the algorithm is rather dumb or specialised only in one of the weights. So instead I would create multiple solutions with some randomness and then let a CNN score them. (The CNN I would also train with solutions with different qualities. Those qualities need to be specified and the optimal solutions gets quality 1.)

Answer (score -1):

I fully understand the issue.  My probability teach in college used to ask the same question a lot of times during the semester : If you have a perfectly shuffled deck of cards and you shuffled one more time.  Was the deck more or less random?

The answer was based on the criteria you were using to determine how random the deck was.  Were you using the ranks of the cards or the suits.  And what game were you playing.  Bridge, 5 card stud, or 7 hand.

Over the years I played many games of cards with friends.  I used to get upset when one friend used to shuffle the cards 8 and 10 times and slow down the game.  Always thought of my professor.

About 25 years later I took a post graduate Probability course that included modeling.  I had a final project that I had to pick.  I wrote a program that shuffled decks of cards and used for the criteria the types of poker hand that were dealt for both 5 hand and 7 hand poker.

My first results were strange.  When I shuffled 1 and 8 times I got exactly same results.  Also with 2 & 9, and then with 3 & 10.  I finally found the issue.  When you did a perfect shuffle by dividing the cards into 2 piles of 26 and then shuffled alternating the cards between the two pile, and did this 7 times you got the exact same deck as when you started.

Lesson learned.  Change the method of shuffling so it wasn't perfect.  It is the same with your problem.  As you developed different solutions you have to go back and reevaluate the criteria and in some cases go back and get additional inputs.

I'm wondering if Dijkstra algorithm can help.  You basically have a graph and like Dijkstra trying to get best path.  With any graph solution you have Nodes with neighbors and trying to connect neighbors.  So best solution is to first determine the nodes and neighbors.  You input isn't clear as where the nodes and neighbors are located.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, hopefully you can explain a bit more. How can I use the thousands pairs of files I have with Dijkstra?

Comment: Just for getting best path.  Actually you have a "Packing Problem" in disguise.  the Roman Originally try to solve the packing issue when going to war.  They looked for a solution of how to pack their chariots.  Put to much in one chariot and it went slow and could topple over.  Put too little in a chariot and you needed more chariots.  Items are different sizes so their are lots of combinations similar to your many different factors.  So I would look up on web solutions for the Packing Problem.  Scientist are still looking to solve problem 2000 years latter.